# clojure.lang, etc. api

Tags: api, documentation, clojure

Are the JavaDocs for clojure.lang, etc. available online? Do I need to build it myself from the Clojure source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want descriptions for functions and even examples, visit [ClojureDocs](http://clojuredocs.org)

you can even contribute ;)

Comment: Aye jeust mite, if people can stand my creative spelling. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Javadocs don't exist, per se. If you look at the Java source code, it's very sparsely documented. Certainly you could generate a skeleton yourself, but it probably wouldn't be all that useful anyway as much of the language is self-implemented (in clojure), using Java mostly for bootstrapping the core functionality. I don't think clojure.lang package is really intended to be used directly.

To learn about Clojure functions you can:

- Use (doc) and (find-doc) from a repl
- Use the API reference at clojure.org
- See ClojureDocs, per @Belun's answer